# JavaScript on mouse down,up http requests

Tags: javascript, httprequest

How can I send http request using JavaScript on mouse down and up. I would send different request on up and down action. Thanks!

Comment: Try taking the keywords from that sentence and putting them into google. Or try googling `javascript ajax`. This might help too: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi, tnx for your replay, I'm not sure if this is ajax request(IP camera PTZ control) http://prntscr.com/3ixk3q , if no can you please tell me how it's called so I can do more research. TNX!

Answer (score 1):

with javascript:

```
function onMouseDown() {
  // do http request
}

function onMouseUp() {
  // do http request
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onmousedown="javscript:onMouseDown()" onmouseup="javascript:onMouseUp()">Click Me!</a>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D6qs5/

use google to find reference about ajax so you can do the http requests